# Upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 (from 16.04) - why I had to change downlad from main server & it is ok?

Tags: 16.04, 17.04, source-code, domain-server

So I tried to upgrade from 16.04 & it failed to do that (I think error read "can't download package"). I messed around and noticed that under updates it said "download from" my country's server - I changed it into "download from main server" and manage to upgrade my system with no problem.

Also, under the same tab of software & updates-> Ubuntu software I "source code" NOT checked with a V (I marked it as well before upgrading).

I'm just asking did I do the right thing? what do they mean? should I switch back (download updates from my country's server + un check the V from "source code")?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't doing anything where you need the source code, it doesn't matter whether or not you check the source code repositories, as you aren't making use of them. It shouldn't hurt to have them. I would not recommend unselecting the source repo, on the chance you may be using it (even unintentionally).

Downloading from the main server is fine. There may have been an issue with your local (country) server, but such issues should go away quickly as that server syncs with the main servers.  You *should* be fine to switch back, but it should work just fine leaving your setup as-is.